# 'main' in 'build' cannot be applied to'(groovy.lang.closure'

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model{
   android{
       ...
       ndk{
          ...
       }

       sources{
           main{
               jni{
                   sources{
                       srcDir "/src/main/**mydir**"
```

The above piece of code is resulting in the following error/warning:

'main' in 'build' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang,closure)'

Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found out ...

sources{ **all** { jni

works!